# How to Manually Label Documents in Azure Form Recognizer for Custom Model Training?

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I am trying to label my sample in Document Intelligence Studio(form recognizer)
with "Custom extraction model". So my issue is when I run the "Run layout" it identifies the text. After I will start Labelling text based on my tags(example: rev_key).

Here my issue is that **"DOM:"** and **"21-JULY-2022"** are both mixed
so I can't tag them separately.

Is there any way I can adjust these polygon shapes as per my need, here I want to adjust this entire selection to  **"DOM:"** and **"21-JULY-2022"** separately.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can adjust these polygon shapes as per my need, here I want to adjust this entire selection to **"DOM:"** and **"21-JULY-2022"** separately.

***Here, we can manually adjust the polygon shapes to achieve the desired tagging.***

- Select the area where the text is overlapping or where you need to adjust the polygon shapes.

**"DOM" :**
[image]

**"DATE" :**
[image]

In the above image I have taken `draw region` and selected required area which is needed and given the `field name` then it recognized and taken the sub type as `string`/`Date`.

**2nd approach :**

- We can as take the selected as a second picture by cropping as I did check below.

[image]

[image]